# Sci-kit SVC: random_state producing different results on mac and my docker image

Tags: python, macos, numpy, docker, scikit-learn

I have a python program running on my MAC, with the following dependencies:

> numpy==1.11.2
>
> scipy==0.18.1
>
> scikit-learn==0.17.1
>
> pymongo==3.4.0
>
> redis==2.10.5
>
> requests==2.12.3

I am trying to classify sentences based on some training data.
Then I want to deploy this python package using a Docker image. Using the [SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) algorithm

> numpy.random.seed(100)
>
> classifier = SVC(probability=True,random_state=100)

This produces different results within Docker and my local system though. The Python version is 2.7.13 in both environments.

Is there a way to set a single seed so that I can get the same results in my local environment as on my deployed environment?

If I install it on a colleague's MAC, the results are consistent with my local environment. This makes me believe that the random number generator is not OS independent. Any way to get it to be?

Thanks and good day